# How can I make Windows 10 not swap audio devices when turning off bluetooth headset?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I've recently started using bluetooth headphones. The issue I'm having with it is when I turn them off, Windows sees them as disconnected, and swaps to another audio output device. This wreaks havoc in applications that aren't set up to properly handle this, mostly games. This causes problems ranging from no longer outputting audio until the application is restarted to locking up my entire system.

Is there a way I can make Windows keep the same audio device active, even when turning the headphones off and Windows sees them as disconnected?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Given the normal circumstances / model, the audio device you were using (your bluetooth headphone) is *gone*, just like when you were using a USB DAC and you unplug it from the computer. So the only way to "keep the same device" would be to have a "proxy" device. *I* am not aware of a software that virtualize such a proxy device, and the only thing I can think of is a USB bluetooth audio transmitter (an audio-specific one that deals with the BT part all by itself and presents itself to the system as a USB sound card, e.g. Creative BT-W4.)

Comment: Agreed - keeping an audio device active when it's turned off will just mean no audio at all.

Comment: No audio is fine, of course if the headset is off I'd have no audio. I'm just wanting it to not change to a different device upon disconnection, for it to somehow see that it's still a valid output device despite being disconnected.

Comment: You could perhaps disable the other audio device, so Windows won't have a fall-back device once you turn the headset off.

Comment: Doing that at least prevented any hard crash from occurring, though it still fails to output audio to the headphones without restarting the problematic applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Tom Yan about a virtual proxy got me searching to see if such a thing existed. I found a number of programs that did just that but had similar crashing issues when turning off the headphones. I ultimately did find one that did what I needed and didn't have any crashes.

**VoiceMeeter** ([Link](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/))

It creates a virtual audio device, then pipes any output sent to that virtual device to whichever physical device you choose. I simply had to set that virtual device as the default sound output in Windows Sound Settings, then set VoiceMeeter to send audio output to the headphones, as well as setting it to restart its Audio Engine automatically on device disconnection.